# mat-tooltip white space, multiline

Tags: angular, angular-material

i need to split text and move sentence on next line in tooltip.

What i tried:

```html
<mat-icon *ngIf="datasetLotStatus" class="left-side__icon"
              matTooltip="Multiline Tooltip &#13; This is second line"
              matTooltipPosition="above">
      warning
    </mat-icon>
```

```html
<mat-icon *ngIf="datasetLotStatus" class="left-side__icon"
              [matTooltip]="tooltipMessage"
              matTooltipPosition="above"
              [matTooltipClass]="'warning-tooltip'">
      warning
    </mat-icon>
```

```css
::ng-deep .cdk-overlay-container, .cdk-global-overlay-wrapper {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

*emphasized text*

```css
.warning-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line!important;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 9px!important;
}
```

```js
public readonly tooltipMessage: string = `Next line Next Line.
    View Analysys
    lollollol`;
```

[image: its looks like this anyway]

SOLUTION :

```css
.cdk-overlay-container .warning-tooltip {
  white-space: pre-line!important;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 9px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&#13;` with `&#013;` in matTooltip